# Chained pipeline (default execute) in wercker dont produce results

Tags: continuous-integration, wercker

I have following pipeline in wercker. They are exactly same for reproducing issue purpose.

```
setup:
  steps:
    - script:
      name: set yarn cache
      code: yarn config set cache-folder $WERCKER_CACHE_DIR/yarn
    - script:
      name: install dependencies
      code: yarn
    - script:
      name: ls
      code: ls
    - script:
      name: test-unit
      code: yarn test

test-unit:
  steps:
    - script:
      name: set yarn cache
      code: yarn config set cache-folder $WERCKER_CACHE_DIR/yarn
    - script:
      name: install dependencies
      code: yarn
    - script:
      name: ls
      code: ls
    - script:
      name: test-unit
      code: yarn test
```

One is configured to execute on push, second configured to execute after first one.
[image: workflow]

[image: pipelines]
The problem is that pipeline doesnt produce same results. In second pipeline  my command e.g. yarn test produce empty result within few seconds. In first ( that is executed on push) tests run fine.

Here is output from first pipeline:

```
export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/pipeline/script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12"
export WERCKER_STEP_ID="script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12"
export WERCKER_STEP_OWNER="wercker"
export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="/report/script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12/numbers.ini"
export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="/report/script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12/message.txt"
export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="/report/script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12/artifacts"
source "/pipeline/script-3bab60c8-5cfd-4b86-9aa3-733e93e12d12/run.sh" < /dev/null
yarn run v1.7.0
$ jest --verbose
PASS src/components/auth/__tests__/passwordValidation.spec.js
  Password Validation Component
    ✓ renders a vue instance (27ms)
    ✓ show all errors for invalid password (16ms)
    ✓ show no errors for valid password (6ms)

PASS src/components/__tests__/payment.spec.js
  Payment Form Component
    ✓ renders a vue instance (44ms)
   ..... 

Test Suites: 7 passed, 7 total
Tests:       24 passed, 24 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.261s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 4.49s.
```

Here is output from second pipeline with problem:

```
export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/pipeline/script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9"
export WERCKER_STEP_ID="script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9"
export WERCKER_STEP_OWNER="wercker"
export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="/report/script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9/numbers.ini"
export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="/report/script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9/message.txt"
export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="/report/script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9/artifacts"
source "/pipeline/script-22826921-2896-40cc-a7f2-d99d0c5377b9/run.sh" < /dev/null
yarn run v1.7.0
$ jest --verbose
Done in 0.08s.
```

So thats a problem that command in my chained pipeline produce no results. ls command return same content in both first and second pipeline. And the problem is not only for jest, other things like build, lint etc produce same zero results in second pipeline.

What happens and how to fix it to make commands work in chained pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in wercker where symbolic links in the second pipeline were not handled correctly.  This bug is fixed and your pipelines should work now!  Please tell us if it doesn't work for you.